# Loading Numbers from a File Instead of Words

Tags: java, swing, file, io

```java
package jtextareatest;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Jtextareatest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("test.txt");
        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("WHAT??");
        frame.setSize(640, 480);
        JTextArea textarea = new JTextArea();
        frame.add(textarea);
        
        int c;
        while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
            textarea.setText(textarea.getText() + Integer.toString(c));
        }
        
        frame.setVisible(true);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

When this runs, instead of placing the correct words from the file, it instead places random numbers that have no relevance to the words. How can I fix this?

Comment: If I write "test" to test.txt, and run your program, it yields 116 101 115 116 10 glued together. These numbers are the ascii-values you asked for (c=in.read reads bytes, but returns ints, to be able to return a -1 as error-indicator, doesn't it? You should use a Scanner instead.

Comment: What is the encoding of `test.txt`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're presumably reading a text file (`"test.txt"`) in binary mode (using `FileInputStream.get`).

I suggest you use some `Reader` or a `Scanner`.

Try the following for instance:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));
while (scanner.hasNextInt())
    textarea.setText(textarea.getText() + scanner.nextInt());
```

---

Btw, you probably want to build up the string using a [`StringBuilder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) and do `textarea.setText(stringbuilder.toString())` in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Use the read() method provided by the JTextComponent API:

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader( "test.txt" );
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
textArea.read( br, null );
br.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read%28%29

> Reads a *byte* of data from this input stream.

and the return type is int, not char or something.

So do what aioobe said.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but you should be able to cast the byte (integer) to a character as well:

```
int c;
while ((c = in.read()) != -1)
{
    textarea.setText(textarea.getText() + Character.toString((char)c));
}
```

However, aioobe's answer is probably still better.